# Python - non-clumsy way to enumerate over filtered dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code like this (`d` is some dictionary and `s` is some set):

```
for i, (k, v) in enumerate((k, v) for k, v in d.items() if k in s):
    ...
```

Even if we ignore the ugly repetition, all literals actually have substantial length, so repeating `k` and `v` 3 times is not an option. What's the best way to write it? Right now, we use the following (also ugly) option:

```
i = -1
for k, v in d.items():
    if k not in s:
        continue
    i += 1
    ...
```

Another option:

```
for i, (k, v) in enumerate((k, d[k]) for k in d if k in s):
    ...
```

, but it basically has the same amount of repetitions.

I'm OK with using any library which is shipped by default (i.e. without `pip install`).

Comment: Two steps? Create intermediate filtered dict first, simple code. Then enumerate over that dict, also simple code. You can take one liners too far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With one extra line, but much less complexity, you could do:

```
for i, k in enumerate(filter(s.__contains__, d)):
    v = d[k]
```

A variation of this uses set intersection (that may scramble your insertion order though):

```
for i, k in enumerate(s & d.keys()):
    v = d[k]
```

Answer (score 0):

dict comprehension is the fastest way to filter a dict:

```
filtered_dict = {key: value for key, value in d.items() if key in s}
```

Therefore, I would suggest to define a task function that does the job on the items and do everything inside this dict comprehension:

```
def task(key, value):
    # do the required job on the dict items
    ....
    return result


{key: task(key, value) for key, value in d.items() if key in s}
```

The result is a dict that contains the computed result for each key/value item. Of, course, you can add `enumerate`if an index is required in addition.